# SendKeys to another application's form

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I created a Process.
That one has a MainWindow I want to SendKeys.Send("+F") (CTRL+F) to, but I don't know how to do this.

So how is this done?

Comment: It sounds like every example requires a window of your created process to be brought to the foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need something like the following to set focus to an external window:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

        if (process.Length > 0)
            SetForegroundWindow(process[0].MainWindowHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: More answers can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787057/need-to-activate-a-window

Answer (score 2):

For Ctrl key you need to precede the key code with ^. something like:

```
SendKeys.Send("^F");
```

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I still need to give the main-window of the Process the focus first.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following helps. This maximized WMP then sends Ctrl+P to play the paused music:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint nCmdShow);
```

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, "Windows Media Player");
if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    // Maximize WMP
    ShowWindow(handle, (uint) WindowShowStyle.Maximize);
    // Use SwitchToThisWindow(handle, false) OR SetForegroundWindow(handle)
    SetForegroundWindow(handle);
    // Make sure the window is brought to the froeground
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    // Use SendKeys OR SendInput API
    SendKeys.SendWait("^p");
    // Minimize WMP
    ShowWindow(handle, (uint)WindowShowStyle.Minimize);
}

Comment: SetForegroundWindow is very likely to fail.  Check the return value.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am not really expert with Windows API but I needed to create a program that resumes and pauses WMP because my first laptop didn't have a key for pause and resume and the above is really working.