# WPF Fake Full Screen

Tags: c#, wpf, api, window

I have a project that automates/controls other Window applications by simulating keystrokes. To simulate keystrokes, I need to bring the window of that application to the front. When this is in progress, you can see the whole process on the screen.

However, I want to have a fake full screen to cover that up. If this is possible, I would also like to display something on the fake full screen, such as the progress bar.

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is to make your main form be displayed in "windowed full screen" mode that is right ?

So in order to do that, you need to set your window size to your screen size.

A way to do it would be the following, in your WPF class :

```
this.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
this.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
```

Or

```
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

To bring a window forward, you can also use :

```
myWindow.Activate();
```

or

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent other windows overlaying your window when it is deactivated you can add the method, I'd use the solution at [WPF Always On Top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050426/wpf-always-on-) (I've it used before and it worked well for me), to the `Deactivated` event of the window:

```
private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window window = (Window)sender;
    window.Topmost = true;
}
```

If you would like to show a progress bar in a fullscreen window when your operation is in progress, you could do something like:

```
private Window CreateFullScreenLoadingBar()
{
    Window fullscreenWindow = new YourLoadingBarWindow();

    fullscreenWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    fullscreenWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    fullscreenWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    fullscreenWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;

    fullscreenWindow.Deactivated += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = (Window)sender;
        window.Topmost = true;
    };            
}
```

Usage:

```
...
Window loadingBar = CreateFullScreenLoadingBar();
fullscreenWindow.Show();
fullscreenWindow.Activate();

// Your code

loadingBar.Close();
...
```

Where `YourLoadingBarWindow` is a window containing a progress bar or whatever you want the user to see.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I use setforeground() to another application, would this fake window be underneath that? In other words, this fake window won't always be on the top?

Comment: @M no this full screen window should always be on top, because of  `window.Topmost = true` is executed when the window is deactivated. I've tested it briefly and it seemed to work well

Comment: Okay I will give it try today

Comment: Unfortunately, "Topmost" method did not work. A full size window works, but when the program Setforeground() another window, the full size window goes away.

Comment: @MHwang Have you tried using the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.activate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Window_Activate method rather than `SetForground()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787098/10772348 @TheCodeKing mentions in the comment that SetForground() needs used to control an application from another process, which is my case

Comment: @MHwang Ah okay, just seen this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/697915fe-7cc2-4c6f-8f96-ecc6a4924858/always-on-top-even-in-fullscreengames?forum=wpf, where they use window.Active() at the end of the method subsribed to `Window.Deactivated` - perhaps that might make a difference? If not I'm not too sure what else to try :(

Comment: @MHwang Also If that doesn't work I've just had an idea to use a `Popup` control (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview) as the whole point of a popup is to always overlay windows. However the only issue with a `Popup` is the fact that it can only cover up to 75% of the screen - Not ideal but definitely a potential work around to your issue